# C++: modifying private attribute of one class in other class

Tags: c++, class

I want to allow class B's object to send its ID to A's object. So A's ID can be set to B's ID. My question is whether it is a "good idea" in "object oriented design" to change the content of A's ID in B class, as I've written below?

```
class A
{
private:
    string ID;

public:
    A()
    {
        ID = "empty";
    }

    void set_ID(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
};

class B
{
private:
    string B_ID;

public:
    B(string id)
    {
        B_ID = id;
    }

    void put_request(A& a)
    {
        a.set_ID(B_ID);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b("my ID");
    b.put_request(a);
}
```

Comment: Do you need a `friend` class? When it comes to modifying privates, it's never a good idea from an Object-Oriented design, however life is full of compromises.

Comment: @tadman No I don't want to use friend class.

Comment: If you're using a `public` interface, I don't see the problem. That's your way of declaring that modifications to `ID` are allowed via the `set_ID` method. The signature should probably be `void set_ID(const string& id)` to be more conventional C++.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what's your actual requirement. May be `query()` is a very unintelligible function name chosen?

Comment: If A's id should only be changed by B, then A should have the function taking a B reference, and not provide a setter.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I changed query () to put_request() to make it more clearer.

Comment: Assume that after B places its ID, A wants to give B update about  the status of its order (e.g. order dispatched). So B needs to have an attribute that should be set by A. My question is: " How can this be done?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly how **Encapsulation** works. It is one of the pillars of Object oriented design paradigm. It refers to keeping the data in private fields and allowing their modification and retrieval through some other (likely setter and getter) methods.

Comment: Assume that after B places its ID, A wants to give B update about the status of its order (e.g. order dispatched). So B needs to have an attribute that should be set by A. My question is: " How can this be done?"

Comment: A is an instance in B. B can modify A but for A to let B know that something has happened, you would need to get some field in A (you should make this call from B). This field in A should be set immediately after there is an update to your order status. So you may want to consider adding an extra field.